# Partitioned cookies (CHIPS) across framed subdomains

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, chips, partitioned

I have an application hosted at one.thirdparty.com that is iframed into another site hosted at site.example.com.

one.thirdparty.com sets a cookie and can redirect users to a subdomain two.thirdparty.com. This subdomain is still iframed within site.example.com

Today, these cookies can be read by the subdomain within the iframe. However, with Chromes third party cookie phaseout it is unclear if when one.thirdparty.com sets a partitioned cookie, if two.thirdparty.com will be able to read/access the partitioned cookie (if it is still iframed within site.example.com)

I am preparing an update to comply with third party cookie phaseout so I’m wondering if I can continue to use cookies (partitioned) or if I need to explore other options